# Dynamic Oauth2 Redirect URL for subdomains

Tags: php, api, redirect, oauth

I have built a web app (in html & php) which interacts with an api via Oauth2 curl commands.

The app comprises of a main site (for example www.myapp.com) on which users can register and create new sites as subdomains (for example www.newsite.myapp.com)

On the new site users are presented with a button to action the api call.

The api call for the base site (e.g. www.myapp.com) works fine as I have simply set the oauth redirect url to return to the base url (i.e. www.myapp.com) I'm now stuck with utilizing the oauth process to interact with the api for subdomains as I want the redirect url to return the the subdomain.

Is there any way to set the redirect URL for oauth2 api interaction dynamically to solve this?

Many thanks,

Matt

Comment: What you have tried and What error you are getting ?

Comment: To be honest I don't even know where to start, I have to set the redirect URL on the API server to match the redirect URL passed through via the Oauth2 call, I can call each subdomain URL easily but don't know how to match that to that set to the Oauth server, I was wondering if there is a standard approach to this? Do you know if its possible to set a dynamic redirect url on an Oauth server?

Comment: Were you able to find any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Authorization Server that you use. The spec does not prevent having dynamic redirect URLs - within certain boundaries - but as it may quickly lead to security vulnerabilities the recommendation is to make redirect URI validation as tight as possible. Depending on your Authorization Server implementation it may allow for flexibility wrt. subdomains or not.